# Error de Angular SCRIPT1002 compatible con Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

El módulo hijo alberga el desarrollo a implementar, por lo que debe entenderse que los 2 proyectos (Angular) deben configurarse de forma independiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He seguido los pasos para habilitar Internet Explorer, pero solo obtengo el error de

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error vendor.js (95940,1)

Los archivos y las modificaciones realizadas son:

-- Ir a **tsconfig.json** cambiar a target: "es5" en lugar de "es2015".

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "./node_modules/child-module",
  ]
}
```

-- Ir a **polyfills** y descomentar algunas líneas y npm install --save `'classlist.js'` `'web-animations-js'`

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'core-js/es/reflect';

import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

En el package aparecen instalados con las versiones `"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312"` `"mdn-polyfills": "^5.20.0"`

-- Finalmente, descomentar las líneas para IE 9-11 del archivo **browserslist**.

Comment: Y con qué comando compilas?

Comment: ¿Usas alguna librería aparte de Angular y que no sea una extensión para Angular? Puede ser que se esté añadiendo entera sin transpilarla y no sea compatible con IE11 (porque tenga funciones flecha, por ejemplo). En tu lista de node_modules veo popperjs, que necesita polyfills para IE11

Comment: @Alfabravo para levantar el local con el "ng serve" sin más, abriéndolo en IE ya veo el error de compilación que comento arriba. En cuanto la compilación del código es trabajo del Jenkins, ¿hay algo con esto deba de tener en cuanta?

Comment: @PabloLozano se está usando bootstrap y material por lo pronto.

Comment: Puede que te sirva saber que angular 12 ya no tienen soporte para IE 11.